# Connection could not be established with host smtp.domain.com :stream_socket_client():

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send emails after user registration on laravel. But when i tried to send emails am getting following error.

**Connection could not be established with host smtp.domain.com :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.domain.com
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I have already clear the cache. Also I contact with my provider and tells me that the ports are open.

Comment: It can't find the IP for your smtp server. See if you can ping it, or try nslookup, to make sure the lookup is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I look up for the email settings and change the MAIL_HOST that was in my hosting

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtpout.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=admin@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```